# Mongoose querying for items

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I Have a mongoose model for a coin that has

```
coinName: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
category: {
  type: String,
},
```

I want to get all the coinNames associated with a category

Right now I have this code

```
const coins = await Coin.find().distinct('category',(error, categories) => {
 
})
```

which gives me all the categories of the coins.
How can I get all the coins within a category?

Thank you

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9zhp9SeRKVJ) what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you want.
So if you want to group every coin by category, you could do it like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZWHZ7rV6_0j)

Or if you just want to find the coins that match [one](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rEEvc6JOeZg) or [more](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BU8ImhclwgF) categories.

Comment: is it possible to return distinct coins with aggregate? when i use your aggregate code, since i have duplicate coin names in my database i need something to get only one

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of your duplicate data, and what output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

try find expretion give filter

```
const coins = await Coin.find({
  category: 'catagory name'
})
```